# Cross mixed effects model in R as a Mathematical Formula

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

Mixed effects models(MEM) can be nested or crossed. For crossed models specifically, how would the below R code look as a mathematical formula in an academic paper? There are multiple random and fixed effects.

```
M1 = lmer(Y ~ A +  B + C + D  + E  + ( 1| FFF) + (1|GGG), data))
```

There is plenty of literature on Crossed MEM. It just doesn't show the R to mathematical formula write up. Nested MEM's do have lots of examples of code to paper but I am battling to understand if the nested and crossed have the same mathematical formulation in papers.

Comment: There is an R package called [equatiomatic](https://datalorax.github.io/equatiomatic/) which supports lme4 models. Maybe, it could help

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestion! Much appreciated.